# Azure ML - there is no package called 'som'

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to use "Azure ML" execute R script module. I have created a zip 4 packages I required and trying to install the libraries. Its giving me error for 1 package "som", rest all working fine. When I have tried same "som" package in my local machine, it is working fine.

I have downloaded all the libraries from CRAN and are the latest one.

Any clues where it can go wrong?

Here us my R script code

```
install.packages("src/plyr_1.8.4.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/RODBC_1.3-14.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/sqldf_0.4-10.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/som_0.3-5.1.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)

library(RODBC)
library(plyr)
library(sqldf)
library(som)
```

Here is error during execution

```
Error 
Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:

---------- Start of error message from R ----------

there is no package called 'som'
```

Comment: It resolved. The problem was not specifying the exact location of installed path. Changed to  library(som, lib.loc=”.”)

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur due to 'som' package has a dependency. Mostly this error occurs with the packages having a dependency related to JVM runtime. Unfortunately still AzureML doesn't support JVM runtime.